# Is there a shorter way to do exactly this?

Tags: python-3.x

I'm trying to find away to do this in a shorter way I don't like not using else in the end because it looks weird without it. This works for me for some reason. If I add the, " else: return True" it will only look at the first true from the list and then return True but won't check the rest... and will end the function

```
b = [[True, True, True], [True, True, True], [True, True, False]]

for i in range(3):
    for j in range(3):
        if b[i][j] == False:
             return False
return True
```

Comment: I don't get it, is this the only way?
i put return True outside the for loop because if all of the for loop works out it will return false but if it doesn't it will skip over to true because the list only has true's inside.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use either [`all`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/functions.html#all) or [`any`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/functions.html#any) to do this:

```
all(all(x) for x in b)
```

OR

```
not any(not y for x in b for y in x)
```

In either case, the value of the expression will be the same as the return value of your original function. Like your original loop, both of these expressions are short-circuiting: they will stop as soon as a `False` element in encountered in the nested lists.

In your original code, returning `True` on the first element naturally ends the function. That's just how `return` works. If you absolutely must have an `else` clause to please your inner aesthete (I would recommend against it), use `else: continue` instead. This is totally superfluous (and therefore generally undesirable), but it will instruct the loop to continue until a `False` is found instead of returning from the function immediately.

Answer (score 2):

I guess a pretty short way to accomplish this would be:

```
return all(i for l in b for i in l)
```

Comment: This has one advantage and one disadvantage over a nested `all` in my opinion: Advantage is that you only need to exit one function when the short circuiting takes effect. Disadvantage is the legibility of the backwards for loops. Either way, +1